# Magento 2.3.0 - Can't set to production mode

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, template, magento2.3.0

I want to put my store on production mode, I use this command on ssh:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

And I have this output:

```
Enabling maintenance mode
Config "dev/debug/debug_logging = 0" has been saved.
Starting compilation
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
Disabling maintenance mode
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php -f /home/store/public_html/m2/bin/magento setup:di:compile`
```

I check the `system.log` and there I have this error:

```
[2019-07-18 08:03:53] main.CRITICAL: Unable to get content for 'frontend/theme/store/en_US/Magento_Swatches/css/swatches.css' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\NotFoundException(code: 0): Unable to get content for 'frontend/theme/store/en_US/Magento_Swatches/css/swatches.css' at /home/store/public_html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php:187)"} []
```

In my custom theme is nothing related to the Magento_Swatches and much more I don't use Swatches.

What can I do to can enable the Production Mode?

Thank you

Comment: Try skip compilation `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try editing your **`env.php`** file inside the folder:

> app → etc

And set **MAGE_MODE** to **production**